# Wrong user when pushing to heroku?

Tags: heroku

When I'm pushing using `git push heroku master` the app gets uploaded on a wrong user that I'm not using anymore.

How can I switch to the correct one I'm currently using?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just copy your heroku files to a new folder, then from there `heroku create` and have control